# Is there anyway to select a task on a gantt chart with plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, gantt-chart

I am using Plotly to plot a Gantt Chart:

```
fig = ff.create_gantt(df, colors=dict_of_colors, index_col='Color', title=None, group_tasks=True)
```

As result I have:

[Gantt Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPauM.png)

Is there a way to select one or more tasks on the chart by clicking on the label that appears on the left so that only the bars of the selected tasks appear on the chart?

Comment: No, it's a static image. You can't "select" anything by clicking on a part of an image.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.